# Binance WSS api url is being treated as HTTPS on both Google Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, websocket, binance

I am trying to run the following code from my chrome browser

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io('wss://stream.binance.com:9443');

socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('binance [socket] Connected');
});

socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
    console.log('binance [socket] Disconnected:', reason);
});

socket.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log('binance [socket] Error:', error);
});
```

But what I got is this:
[image]

Why it is converting my WSS url to Https? and this problem is for this binance streaming api only I am not getting this problem when I use the following url

```
wss://streamer.cryptocompare.com
```

So, how should I overcome this problem? Thanks.

P.S. I have tried this code on both Firefox and Google Chrome both are behaving same for the Binance Websocket Api URL.

Answer (score 0):

After much struggling, I still don't know why WSS url gets converted to HTTPs but now I know how to overcome it.

Use `WebSocket` class of `JavaScript` directly or a wrapper/library which uses `WebSocket` class of `JavaScript` internally then you won't get the above issue.

P.S.
This answer is just to save someone like me from going through the pain of days of searching and frustration, though part of the above question is still unanswered :) .